# nginx, php-cgi and "No input file specified."

Tags: permissions, nginx, php-cgi

I'm trying to get nginx to play nice with php-cgi, but it's not quite working how I'd like. I'm using some set variables to allow for dynamic host names--basically anything.local. I know that stuff is working because I can access static files properly, however php files don't work. I get the standard "No input file specified." error which normally occurs when the file doesn't exist, but it definitely does exist and the path is correct because I can access the static files in the same path. It could possibly be a permissions thing, but I'm not sure how that could be an issue. I'm running this on Windows under my own user account, so I think it should have permission unless php-cgi is running under a different user without me telling it to. >.>

Here's my config;

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
 gzip  on;

 server {
  # Listen for HTTP
  listen 80;

  # Match to local host names.
  server_name  *.local;

  # We need to store a "cleaned" host.
  set $no_www $host;
  set $no_local $host;

  # Strip out www.
  if ($host ~* www\.(.*)) {
   set $no_www $1;
   rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://$no_www$1 permanent;
  }

  # Strip local for directory names.
  if ($no_www ~* (.*)\.local) {
   set $no_local $1;
  }

  # Define default path handler.
  location / {
   root   ../Users/Stephen/Documents/Work/$no_local.com/hosts/main/docs;
   index  index.php index.html index.htm;

   # Route non-existent paths through Kohana system router.
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?kohana_uri=$request_uri;
  }

  # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
  location ~ \.php$ {
   root   ../Users/Stephen/Documents/Work/$no_local.com/hosts/main/docs;
   fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
   fastcgi_index  index.php;
   include        fastcgi.conf;
  }

  # Prevent access to system files.
  location ~ /\. {
   return 404;
  }
  location ~* ^/(modules|application|system) {
   return 404;
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out.

The Windows version of nginx appends the root path to the executable path, so if it's located at C:\nginx and you want to store your files in C:\www you need to do ../www for the root path. Nginx passes it's odd transformed path to PHP, but PHP doesn't understand it, so I adjusted it to use an absolute path instead.